# How to maximize volume and sound quality of a YouTube video

Tags: youtube, encoding

We're trying to produce highest-possible quality (short, promotional, sound intensive) videos for YouTube, and want to achieve fullest possible sound.

There's a huge range of sound volume/quality across different videos on YouTube.

Examples:

- Quality sound - Vevo music videos

  .
- Very loud:

We assemble our soundtracks in Logic Pro, our videos in After Effects / Premiere, and use Adobe Media Encoder to encode to YouTube. What are some steps we can take to get the fullest sound with this production chain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Industry level audio usually heavily compressed as a last step of production. I would guess this is what you are after. This is of course given your initial sound track is of decent quality already. There are plenty of software compressors available on the market and can be used with Logic. I'm not recommending or advertising but just for [example](http://www.gearslutz.com/board/reviews/685890-waves-l1-ultramaximizer.html).

Comment: Eugene- great thanks- wasn't even aware of the concept of compression but now I know what to look for

Comment: @Yarin Hope it helps

Comment: It should be noted that youtube performs its own compression on every video uploaded, so you should export to the least-compressed version you can be bothered with (obviously, larger file=longer to upload). Also, IIRC (last time I checked this was two years ago), youtube uses better-quality (higher bit rate) audio compression for 720p and 1080p videos that it does for SD content, so uploading HD stuff might help.

Comment: @evilsoup Eugene was referring to audio compression as an effect, not the data compression.